# PhantomJS timeout issue when running in headless mode in GitLab CI

Tags: phantomjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use GitLab CI to run some client-side unit test written using QUnit. Now to run the Qunit test I am using the grunt-contrib-qunit plugin. To run these tests in headless mode I am using this plugin which hosts it on a localhost server in a console and runs all unit tests. When running this project locally I am successfully able to run all the unit tests but when I checking in my code which kicks of the CI process, on GitLab, it fails on starting the phantomjs server and gives timeout error. I am also providing the jsbin link of the two text files which are basically the output of the unit test from my console. One file is of my local system and another is from the GitLab CI that runs on GitLab website when I check-in my code.

[Local Console Output File Dump](https://dumptext.com/s4MWITjm#)

[Gitlab CI Output Dump](https://dumptext.com/9MA5hvYS)

Adding my gitlab-ci.yaml file

```
image: node:4.2.2

before_script:
    - dir
    - cd sapui5_repo
    - dir
    - cd app-with-tests

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - npm i
        - npm run test
    cache:
        policy: push
        paths:
        - node_modules
    artifacts:
        paths:
        - built
```

Also adding my gruntfile if that helps

```
/* global module */

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        qunit: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    timeout: 9000,
                    urls: [
                        "http://localhost:9000/webcontent/test/unit/unitTests.qunit.html"
                    ]
                }
            },
            //all: ["webcontent/test/unit/unitTests.qunit.html"],
            options: {
                timeout: 2000,
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                //open: true,
            },
            first: {
                options: {
                    port: 9000,
                    //livereload: 3500,
                    base: "./"
                }
            },
            second: {
                options: {
                    open: {
                        target: "http://localhost:9000/webcontent"
                    },
                    keepalive: true,
                    port: 9000,
                    livereload: 3501,
                    base: "./",
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-connect");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-qunit");


    grunt.registerTask("test", [
        "connect:first", "qunit"
    ]);
    grunt.registerTask("default", [
        "connect:second"
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Can HTTP or localhost be an issue here?